# Vim tab to 2 spaces not working properly

Tags: vim

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab
set autoindent
```

is in my .vimrc. However, my tabbing is inconsistent, sometimes resulting in a tab instead of 2 spaces. Am I missing something? This used to work before upgrading Ubuntu. I mainly program Python.

Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please quantify "sometimes" by giving one example file and line number for which it fails and one example file and line number for which it works.

Answer (score 4):

Set `smarttab` as well. I use `set expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 smarttab`

From vim's `:help smarttab`

> When on, a <kbd>Tab</kbd> in front of a line inserts blanks according to
>   'shiftwidth'.  'tabstop' or 'softtabstop' is used in other places.  A
>   <kbd>backspace</kbd> will delete a 'shiftwidth' worth of space at the start of the
>   line.
>
> When off, a <kbd>Tab</kbd> always inserts blanks according to 'tabstop'
>   or 'softtabstop'.  'shiftwidth' is only used for shifting text left or
>   right shift-left-right.
>
> What gets inserted (a <kbd>Tab</kbd> or spaces) depends
>   on the 'expandtab' option.  Also see ins-expandtab.  When 'expandtab'
>   is not set, the number of spaces is minimized by using Tabs. NOTE:
>   This option is reset when 'compatible' is set.